single slack app in a workspace for multiple environments
I have a single workspace in Slack but there are 4 environments in the infrastructure.
Can I use a single Slack application to work on 4 different environments?
It would be like deploying 4 different instances [as we have 4 environments] using the same token for the single Slack app.
Example:
4 environment named

ABC
XYZ
FOO
BAR

1 Single Application named foobar that has its own set of tokens.
I use errbot with slack backend and would like to use the foobar app's token across all 4 environments. Not sure if it's possible.
We plan to use the same credentials for local development.
During POC, we found that one environment was up and running, and at the same time we used the same tokens for local development but it didn't have any logs for the commands passed as if it wasn't listening at all.
examples of the commands that would be used across all environments.
!server ABC info
!server XYZ info
!server FOO info
!server BAR info


It looks like it isn't possible as the same tokens will be used across all 4 instances where they listen to the same events and have no way of knowing which instance should process the message.
The only way is to use a unique slack app for each environment.
